# How to stream remote output from psexec process

Tags: c#, psexec

I'm trying to run a batch file on a remote system and get the output locally (the batch file runs an SSIS script that has a bunch of output). I can get the remote file to run just fine, but I get no output from it on the local machine.

My code (note, I was trying "ipconfig /all" just as a test):

```
public RunRemoteProcess() {

    _process = new Process();
    _process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = string.Concat(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Resources\psexec.exe"),
        Arguments = "\\remotePCName ipconfig /all"
    };

    _process.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataHandler;
    _process.ErrorDataReceived += ErrorDataHandler;

    _process.Start();
    _process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    _process.BeginErrorReadLine();

}

// _logger below is just a class that writes the data to a file
private void OutputDataHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    _logger.Info(e.Data);
}

private void ErrorDataHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    _logger.Info(e.Data);
}
```

I've found over SO questions/answers that mention using `WaitForExit` but I don't want to write the entire output when it finishes; I want to stream it as it's received.

I've also tried added `RedirectStandardInput = true` to the ProcessStartInfo (as some answers said that worked) but it didn't change anything for me.

Comment: Does it have to be PSExec? Powershell remoting works really well, if you can use it. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/collecting-the-output-of-remoting-commands/

Comment: @MarcE I didn't know that was an option, but it doesn't appear to work. It seems winrm (on the remote machine) is configured to allow remote requests, but I might be getting a permissions issue when trying to invoke the command from my local PC.

Comment: I've used it many times following the steps here, but I guess it's environmentally sensitive so local network / domain / firewalls / user accounts etc may come into play. https://blog.netspi.com/powershell-remoting-cheatsheet/